# How to make my expanding Toolbar overlap my ViewPager? [CoordinatorLayout + Design library v23]

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to achieve the smooth toolbar expanding animation when changing screens - swiping left/right (fragments). Note that when the toolbar is expanding it does not push the content down but simply overlaps it. To illustrate exactly what I am talking about watch the short video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63s6T-7WIRM)
I managed to get a similar behaviour whith 3 fragments and viewpager. When scrolling down on a RecyclerView in one of the fragments the toolbar is hidden and when swiping to another fragment (left/right) the toolbar is expanded programmatically. The problem is when it is expanding it pushes down my viewpager. Again, watch the short video to see what I am talking about, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uMHj5bT1C8)

My current mayout is the following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".UI.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayouy"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tabsHeight"
        style="@style/NavigationTab"/>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/blood_orange"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/dirtyWhite"
    fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
    fab:fab_addButtonSize = "normal"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
    fab:fab_labelsPosition="left"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewpager"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/createPlanBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/blood_orange"
        fab:fab_title="Create a plan"
        fab:fab_size="normal"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_event_white_48dp"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/dirtyWhite"/>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/changeStatusBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/blood_orange"
        fab:fab_size="normal"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_textsms_white_48dp"
        fab:fab_title="Change status"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/dirtyWhite"/>

</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```